# Runtime Error Cannot read property 'environment' of null - Ionic Google Maps

Tags: angular, google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm setting up my Ionic app and I've followed the Google Maps API documentation precisely. However, I have not been able to escape this error I keep getting when I try to run the Maps API:

[image]

And then this is my full code from the HomePage. I have made sure to put in a div in the home.html with the `id="map_canvas"` as well as set the height to 100% in the scss file for it. From what I've seen, the error seems to not like the Environment part, but I have made sure my API key is correct and I've run the correlating cordova commands to set up the google maps plug in. I just cannot see what could be causing this error.

```
import {
  GoogleMaps,
  GoogleMap,
  GoogleMapsEvent,
  GoogleMapOptions,
  Marker,
  Environment
} from '@ionic-native/google-maps';
import { Component } from "@angular/core/";

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  map: GoogleMap;
  constructor() { }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.loadMap();
  }

  loadMap() {

    // This code is necessary for browser
    Environment.setEnv({
      'API_KEY_FOR_BROWSER_RELEASE': 'I_ENTERED_MY_UNRESTRICTED_API_KEY_HERE',
      'API_KEY_FOR_BROWSER_DEBUG': ''
    });

    let mapOptions: GoogleMapOptions = {
      camera: {
        target: {
          lat: 43.0741904,
          lng: -89.3809802
        },
        zoom: 18,
        tilt: 30
      }
    };

    this.map = GoogleMaps.create('map_canvas', mapOptions);

    let marker: Marker = this.map.addMarkerSync({
      title: 'Ionic',
      icon: 'blue',
      animation: 'DROP',
      position: {
        lat: 43.0741904,
        lng: -89.3809802
      }
    });
    marker.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_CLICK).subscribe(() => {
      alert('clicked');
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: check below references if you missing some thing while configure ionic project https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/injecting-environment-variables-into-the-build/111875     https://scotch.io/@chaitanyamankala/adding-environment-for-ionic-23-projects

Comment: set variable environment to blank on initialize.

Comment: @yushin I used the CLI to initiate everything. I assuming this didn't work properly. Do you know where i would initialize it and how?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to build it for whatever platform that you want to use (ex. browser, android, ios) using

> ionic cordova build browser -l

and then this will create the environment for it and thus it will be running. It does not simply work using ionic serve

Comment: @NeerajWalia there is a big switch up between ionic v3 and ionic v4. If you are using v3 you should not need any Environments to make this work. And try to build it for something other the browser. The browser doesn't always work correctly. If you're still having trouble just follow this step by step tutorial using whichever ionic version you have https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/e/2PACX-1vScoho1ensbR4qCI9AIuQN55BZVvK73pAjI7sumDvW3CrxxHnrmpXWUjx2-8CpFibqU1EjLKCRhuthJ/pub?start=false&loop=false&delayms=3000&slide=id.p

Comment: @NeerajWalia You're probably trying `ionic serve` after you build for browser. 
It won't work with serve.
You need to run it for cordova browser: `ionic cordova run browser -l`