# Cannot read property 'environment' of null - ionic native google maps

Tags: google-maps, cordova, ionic-framework

When running my ionic project with `ionic serve -c`

Everytime, I get an this error :

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'environment' of null
   at Function.Environment.setEnv (index.js:1980)
   at HomePage.webpackJsonp.194.HomePage.loadMap (home.ts:98)
   at HomePage.webpackJsonp.194.HomePage.ionViewDidLoad (home.ts:45)
   at ViewController._lifecycle (view-controller.js:486)
   at ViewController._didLoad (view-controller.js:369)
   at NavControllerBase._didLoad (nav-controller-base.js:768)
   at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
   at Object.onInvoke (core.js:4760)
   at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
   at r.run (polyfills.js:3)
```

There is the loadMap method :

```
  loadMap() {
    Environment.setEnv({
      'API_KEY_FOR_BROWSER_DEBUG' : '',
      'API_KEY_FOR_BROWSER_RELEASE' : ''
    })

    this.geoLocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
      this.latitude = resp.coords.latitude;
      this.longitude = resp.coords.longitude;
      console.log(this.latitude);
      console.log(this.longitude);
      let CurrentPosition : LatLng = new LatLng(this.latitude,this.longitude);
      let CameraPosition : CameraPosition<ILatLng> = {
        target : CurrentPosition,
        zoom : 18
      };
      this.addMarker();
      this.map.moveCamera(CameraPosition);
     }).catch((error) => {
       console.log('Error getting location', error);
     });



    this.map = GoogleMaps.create('map_canvas');

  }
```

I don't understand. I only launch my component after the device.isReady() is fired, so it should not be a lifecycle problem.

Do you have any idea as to where does this come from?

Thank you!

EDIT : When using the `ionic cordova run browser -l` command, the map is loaded without error the first time then on some refresh of the webpage, the error appears again, without me changing anything to the code...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem I found the solution on this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/52681481/6560704

You need to build your platforms to create that 'environment' variable, by using CLI for example :

```
ionic cordova build browser -l
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Thank you for your response but unfortunately the problem is still the same. When I refresh the webpage, I still got the same error...

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved !

It was in fact a lifecycle problem. I was attributing the HomePage to the rootPage in app.components.ts before the device was ready.